# Exclude files from being concatenated (MINIT plugin)

Tags: javascript, css, minify

I have some wordpress blogs, and I try to use Minit Plugin https://github.com/kasparsd/minit
But it breaks my Weaver theme. How could I use more specific file exclusion described here ? I mean, some examples !
http://kaspars.net/blog/wordpress/minit-cache-purge-exclude-files-filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To exclude a file from Minit you have to know its script ID that was used during enqueueing the script or style. You can get it from the `id` attribute of the script or style in the HTML source of the page. Take this CSS link as an example:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='rt-wpp-plugin-style-css' href='http://wptavern.com/wp-content/plugins/rt-prettyphoto/css/A.prettyPhoto.css' type='text/css' media='all'/>
```

The ID of this style is `rt-wpp-plugin-style` (notice that we don't include the traling `-css` or `-js` part).

Then we use the appropriate Minit filter:

- `minit-exclude-js` for excluding Javascript files, or
- `minit-exclude-css` for excluding CSS files

like so:

```
add_filter( 'minit-exclude-css', 'custom_minit_exclude_css' );

function custom_minit_exclude_css( $styles ) {

    $styles[] = 'rt-wpp-plugin-style';

    return $styles;

}
```

Comment: This is very informative, thx a lot. I would also appreciate if anyone has time for an example with javascript. This is the thing that gives me headaches. I am a total noob, where should I add the filter.